# How did we come up with this other form for this sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Could someone please tell how is it possible to change this sum  :

$${x_{3}(m)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{n}{N}}\bigg ]\bigg[\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{2}(l)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{l}{N}}\bigg ] e^{j2\pi k\frac{m}{N}}} $$

to :

$$ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{2}(l)\bigg[\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{j2\pi k\frac{m-n-l}{N}}\bigg ]$$

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align}&\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{n}{N}}\bigg ]\bigg[\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{2}(l)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{l}{N}}\bigg ] e^{j2\pi k\frac{m}{N}}\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{n}{N}}x_{2}(l)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{l}{N}} e^{j2\pi k\frac{m}{N}} \text{, distributive law}\\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)x_{2}(l) e^{j2\pi k\frac{m-n-l}{N}} \\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)x_{2}(l) e^{j2\pi k\frac{m-n-l}{N}} \\
&=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{2}(l) \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}e^{j2\pi k\frac{m-n-l}{N}} \\
\end{align}

Notice that we are dealing with finite sum, the order of summation doesn't matter.

Comment: can you please specify how did you use the distributive law in going from :$\\  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\bigg[\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{n}{N}}\bigg ]\bigg[\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{2}(l)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{l}{N}}\bigg ] e^{j2\pi k\frac{m}{N}} $

to : 

$\\ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\sum_{n=0}^{N-1}\sum_{l=0}^{N-1}x_{1}(n)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{n}{N}}x_{2}(l)e^{-j2\pi k\frac{l}{N}} e^{j2\pi k\frac{m}{N}} \\$



Because I think this is really the key step .

Comment: For example $(a+b+c)(d+e+f)=ad+ae+af+bd+be+bf+cd+cd+cf$. Product of sum is the sum of the product.

Comment: Thank you now I can see through it !